# How to determine the number of states of finite automata according to any language?

Tags: finite-automata, state-machine, formal-languages

I have a burning question about finite state machines, that how we can know that this language needs 2 states or 3 states? I mean is there any formula for that?
Although I believe, we would always work to minimize the number of states but still **How can we determine the number of states to be created according to any language or string (without actually constructing the DFA)?**

Answer (score 2):

You are in effect asking about *DFA minimization*. It is a well-studied problem for which a number of algorithms have been developed. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) on it is a good starting point.

The theoretical result which governs the number of states is the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem), but this theorem doesn't give any quick formula. You have to determine the number of equivalence classes in an equivalence relation defined in terms of the language. Hopcroft's algorithm for DFA minimization is essentially an algorithm for determining the equivalence classes in the Myhill-Nerode equivalence relation. I suspect that any attempt to use Myhill-Nerode more directly is going to lead to something similar to Hopcroft's algorithm, though I am not an expert in the field.

Comment: No, Not about minimization! I am just asking is there any way to say that this number of states is going to be created for this language ?

Comment: But you *are* asking a question about minimization -- how many states are required? The naïve answer is to construct the minimal DFA and see how many states it has. If your question is whether or not it is possible to determine the number of states in a minimal DFA without explicitly constructing it -- you should edit your question to make that explicit,

Comment: I am a starter on finite state machines. if there is any DFA that has minimum states even then, can we tell about the number of states that would be used to construct that minimal DFA just by looking at any specific language or strings ?

Answer (score 0):

Aho-corasick multiple pattern matching algorithm is a finite state machine with only 1 state.